# How do i parse out the last portion of a ruby string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this string

```
location = '\\dev-something-again-n2\Staples\Started\477'
location = '\\dev-something-again-n2\Staples\Started\477\'
```

and i need to pull out the 477 out of it...any ideas of a good way to do this ...i was trying

```
location.partition("\")
```

but got nothing ....

Answer (score 4):

```
location.split('\\').last
```

[`partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-partition) isn't the right tool here - it splits once on the string, rather than splitting on all the places it is found, as documented:

```
partition(sep) => [head, sep, tail] click to toggle source
Searches the string for sep and returns the part before it, the sep, and the part after it. If sep is not found, returns str and two empty strings. If no argument is given, Enumerable#partition is called.
```

[`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-split) is the right tool for the job, if you want to do this by breaking the content apart.

Comment: I had (mistakenly) though that a code like yours will return the empty string with the second `location`, but tried and saw that you are correct. Did the specification of `split` change?

Comment: No, you might have still have trouble with empty elements being present on the second location - I figured that once you had the basics you could adapt.  `location.split('\\').reject(&:empty?).last` should do the right thing, though, in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
File.split(location).last
```

or

```
File.basename(location)
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting `File` here? He's parsing a string. (just curious)

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, maybe he's not working with file paths but it sure looks like he is getting a file from a remote computer in Windows.  It looks like `\\hostname\sharename\path\to\file`.

Answer (score 0):

```
location.chomp('\\').match(/(?:.*\\)(.*)/)[1]
```